# getElementsByClassName() with two classes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get all elements with class `a` *or* `b` using `getElementsByClassName()` only once? I'd prefer vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Did not found anything but chaining like parent.getElementsByClassName("Bottom")[0].getElementsByClassName("Left")[0] (using getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can't do it  with **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** method instead use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method with comma separated class selectors.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.a,.b')
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but note that the support for IE8 is only for CSS2 selectors, and there is no support for IE <= 7, so in that case you will need to do two selections by class.

Comment: I see your edit but getElementsByClassName won't work either in IE <= 7, I'm posting an alternative answer just to complete this but yours should be voted as best answer by OP.

Comment: @zoubida13: How is `.a,.b` not just two CSS2 selectors?

Comment: @zoubida13 : I don't think there is people who still using `IE <= 7` :) ;)

Comment: even microsoft doesn't support IE7 anymore. Why companies or devs still do, I can't understand!

Comment: Isn't `querySelectorAll()` much slower performance wise?

Answer (score 44):

You *can* pass more than one class name to `getElementsByClassName()` by separating them with spaces:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2 class3");
```

Now, this differs from the `.querySelectorAll(".class1,.class2,.class3")` approach in that it applies a *conjunction*, not a *disjunction* — "and" instead of "or". Thus

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2 class3");
```

is like

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2.class3");
```

Sometimes you want one, sometimes you want the other. It's definitely true that `.querySelectorAll()` gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: This is not right. It will search for elements that have all three classes

Comment: That is an "AND" not an "OR"

Comment: @epascarello yes I see that; it's just an answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. It will only return elements with all of the specified classes.

Comment: It's an answer in which answers the wrong question, the provided information isn't exactly relevant to the asked question. And more than likely is something the OP already knows. Hence this is mostly noise.

Comment: @Bitterblue it does not force an order of classes; it's the same as using `.c1.c2.c3` with `querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't achieve that with only one [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) call. That function returns elements which have *all* of the classes specified in the first argument as a space-separated string.

There are two possible solution. First is to use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead, which uses CSS selectors.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b")
```

The second solution is to call `document.getElementsByClassName()` twice, turn the results into arrays using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and merge them using [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). To avoid duplicates (for example when element has *both* `a` and `b` class), you have to create a new [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from that array, and then turn it back to array using `Array.from()`.

```
const classA = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("a"))
     ,classB = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("b"))
     ,result = Array.from(new Set(classA.concat(classB)))
```

See demo below:

```js
console.log("first solution", document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b"))

const classA = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("a"))
     ,classB = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("b"))
     ,result = Array.from(new Set(classA.concat(classB)))

console.log("second solution", result)
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

Note that the first solution gives an array-like [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object, whereas the second gives just an array.

Comment: It is pointless to use Set, because it is unsupported in those browsers, what do not support querySelectorAll.

Comment: @Somnium It's not as pointless as it looks like. Babel supports Set, but doesn't support `document.querySelectorAll()` (because it's not part of ECMAScript, but of Web APIs). If you use Babel to compile your code, the second solution will work in all browser. And frankly, I wrote the second solution rather for fun, than as a real solution.

Comment: Array.from is generating issue in internet explorer 11.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add a bit more support, here is a version that is compatible with older versions of IE and uses pure vanilla js :

```
function getElementsByClassNameOr(root, classNameString) // classNameString like '.a, .b' don't forget the comma separator
 {
    var arr = [],
    rx = new RegExp('(^|[ \n\r\t\f])' + classNameString + '([ \n\r\t\f]|$)'),
    elements = root.getElementsByTagName("*");

    var elem;

    for (i=0 ; i < elements.length ; i++) {
        elem = elements[i];
        if (rx.test(elem.className)) {
            arr.push(elem);
        }

    }

    return arr; // will contain all the elements that have one of the classes in ClassNameString, root can be document or a div.
}
```

Comment: This will be very inefficient. Note that by supporting older browsers, one is targeting `much slower` browsers. Performance is in this situation critical, I suggest using multiple calls to `Element.getElementsByClassName` and make use of a concatenated array of the results.

Comment: @Tim you are right about performance, although the fact that performance is critical in this situation is entirely down to your interpretation. And your suggestion is neither valid nor detailed. getElementsByClassName is not fully supported in IE < 9.

Comment: @zoubida13 You are completely right. There seems to be no other way than this answer with better performance.

Comment: @Blender I replaced a comma with a semicolon it was indeed a typo yes.

Comment: @zoubida13: Your code assumes that the class names are right next to one another, so it won't work for `class="a b c"` when you search with `'a c'`.

Comment: This code is quite insecure. Class names can take special chars, like `.[]{}()`. You need to escape those first. Also, the performance can be quite bad in no time. Instead of `(^|[ \n\r\t\f])`, use `(?:^|\s)` and instead of `([ \n\r\t\f]|$)`, use `(?:\s|$)`. Also, change `for (i=0 ; i < elements.length ; i++)` into `for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length ; i++)`.

Comment: Doesn't `classNameString` need to be something like `(?:a|b)` instead of `.a, .b`???