# How to read property input 'value' on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var boxmaterial = document.getElementsByClassName("spb-productoptiontextcolor spb-productoptionbackground")[0].value;
console.log(boxmaterial)
```

I have this code in a script but when I load the page I recieve

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (product.js?2684207326912816513:14)
at u (vendor.js?2684207326912816513:14)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (vendor.js?2684207326912816513:14)
at ready (vendor.js?2684207326912816513:14)
```

This is because the field hasn't loaded yet since it is being loaded dynamically by a plugin.
However when I run the code above in he console window while the page has loaded it works.

Is there a way to select the input and retrieve the value?
You can see the page i am working on here [working site](https://garbanzo-nyc.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/large-square-box)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` selector with multiple class names - use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.spb-productoptiontextcolor,.spb-productoptionbackground')[0].value
```

[getElementsByClassName() with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255293/getelementsbyclassname-with-two-classes)

Comment: If you believe the question is a dupe, please just vote to close it as such.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i was not sure due to the question was about accessing that value but not about using the selector with multiple class names

Comment: yeah that runs in the console and works but when i run it with the page it doesn't work at all. returns Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @user3803699 so there is anything else wrong with your code