# Klaviyo - Javascript Button Tracking

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript script to track button clicks on-site and send information to Klaviyo.
Then I've created a flow in Klaviyo to send email based on a button click "Add To Wishlist"
But, it's not working.

I've used query selector based on this post here:
[getElementsByClassName() with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255293/getelementsbyclassname-with-two-classes)

Because I have 2 classes. Here is a screenshot of them:
 1. On Collection Page
 http://prntscr.com/rn50ok

2.On Product Page:
http://prntscr.com/rn51n0

P.S

I understand this may be basic but I have 0 knowledge on javascript and API's I just used documentation that Klaviyo has and tried to create it based on their Add To Cart code.

```
<script text="text/javascript">
var _learnq = _learnq || [];

var classname = document.querySelectorAll(".yith-wcwl-add-button jas_add_wishlist,.add_nitro_wishlist add_to_wishlist gecko-tooltip");

var myFunction = function() {
_learnq.push(['track', 'Add to Wishlist', item]);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use two classes?  If you just use one, the code is a bit more clean.  Example (using "jas_add_wishlist"):

```
<script text="text/javascript">
var _learnq = _learnq || [];

var classname = document. getElementsByClassName("jas_add_wishlist");

var myFunction = function() {
_learnq.push(['track', 'Add to Wishlist', item]);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
</script>
```