# How to assign css to javascript which have two or more selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

I'm trying to assign a very large block of html and css code with help of javascript. The code works properly in the day mode but I have a little issue with that when it comes to night mode. Given `container` and `img` aren't changing color and other values when night mode is turned on. What mistake did i do?

https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/qBNZagr

Comment: use `var authclass = document.querySelectorAll(".night .profile-container");`

Comment: It will override some existing values. I'm already lazy to change the rest. I will proceed with what @stevetomlin said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work using 2 parameters in your method.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("night profile-container")
```

see: [getElementsByClassName() with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255293/getelementsbyclassname-with-two-classes)

In any case what you are doing is a bad practice, constantly changing the dom like this as its slows the browser rendering repaint. I would instead advise putting in your stylesheet and rending to the dom in one batch.

```css
body.night .profile-container {
/* styles ...*/
}
```

Comment: Also I think the class changing logic `body.classList.add('night');` should be placed in `function toggleNight()` @Maniac Piano

Comment: @ManiacPiano body.night .profile-container  will work, the same way body.night works, unless you are overriding the style. Can you show a new example with it implemented to prove it not working?

Comment: Here - I updated the pen for you with working example - https://codepen.io/inspiraller/pen/oNLBXpL

Comment: @SteveTomlin, I didn't use `!important` declaration when trying it. It worked, Thanks.

Comment: @ManiacPiano Going forward I would discourage using important. It was just to illustrate that you already had styles that were overriding the stylesheeet.

Comment: @SteveTomlin, Thankyou for help. I will follow that.